# pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, None, None, None, 0, -2147352565), None)

Tags: xlwings

I was created example from 
http://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/vba.html 
/*Python 3.5.1 |Anaconda 2.5.0 (32-bit)| (default, Jan 29 2016, 15:46:01)*/
and got error

```
--
---------------------------
Error
---------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>

  File "C:\Python3\mymodule.py", line 7, in rand_numbers

    n = int(Range('Sheet1', 'B1').value)  # Write desired dimensions into Cell B1

  File "C:\Python3\lib\site-packages\xlwings\main.py", line 701, in __init__

    self.xl_sheet = xlplatform.get_worksheet(self.xl_workbook, sheet_name_or_index)

  File "C:\Python3\lib\site-packages\xlwings\_xlwindows.py", line 240, in get_worksheet

    return xl_workbook.Sheets(sheet)

  File "C:\Python3\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 192, in __call__

    return self._get_good_object_(self._oleobj_.Invoke(*allArgs),self._olerepr_.defaultDispatchName,None)

pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, None, None, None, 0, -2147352565), None)



Press Ctrl+C to copy this message to the clipboard.
---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------
```

Comment: i am working in Russian locally and we have "," sign instead "."  for decimal separator

Comment: Just checked   - with dot issues the same

Comment: checked on the xlwings-0.6.4 and  xlwings-0.7.0 issue the same

Comment: When you download the Fibonacci example from the homepage, do you see the same error?

Comment: Standalone Works fine

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Hey so the error means:

```
>>> import win32api
>>> win32api.FormatMessage(-2147352565)
'Invalid index.\r\n'
```

So my guess is that you're trying to write to an inexistent sheet (and yes, we shall be working on easier-to-understand error messages...)

Comment: Yeah !    I was rename list from Лист1 to Sheet1 and this issue was gone

Comment: Ah interesting, so it's struggling with unicode sheet names - I ll open an issue for that.

Answer (score 7):

I've found that you can't use relative paths, and this is the error you get if you do use a relative path.

pass the relative path with os.path.abspath(rel_path) to open the file.

Answer (score 1):

in my case I was trying to refresh an Excel file but one of the required add-ins was disabled.

Answer (score 0):

If the above solutions did not work then my best guess is that the excel file you using is not in focus, I had the same issue while working with xlwing. All you need to do is once select the Excel (kind of set focus event of excel) file and then run the python code.