# win32api.FormatMessage() error

Tags: python, excel, winapi, xlwings

I am trying to get a named Range in code like this:

```
Range(rng_name, index=False).value = df_grouped_a.ix[loc][col]
```

This generates exception:

```
  File "C:/Users/acme/python/s.py", line 149, in <module>
    Range(rng_name, index=False).value = df_grouped_a.ix[loc][col]
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python271\lib\site-packages\xlwings\main.py", line 620, in __init__
    self.row1 = xlplatform.get_first_row(self.xl_sheet, range_address)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python271\lib\site-packages\xlwings\_xlwindows.py", line 122, in get_first_row
    return xl_sheet.Range(range_address).Row
  File "<COMObject <unknown>>", line 3, in Range
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, None, None, None, 0, -2146827284), None)
```

It might be related to the named range issue, but I would like to get the meaning of error code `-2146827284` first.

Unfortunately, the way described here does not work for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36080159

Namely:

```
>>> import win32api
>>> win32api.FormatMessage(-2146827284)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
pywintypes.error: (15100, 'FormatMessage', 'The resource loader failed to find MUI file.')
```

How can I find the error message corresponding to this error code?

Comment: Convert it to unsigned, you get `0x800A03EC`.

Comment: what version of xlwings are you using? and is there a possibility to upgrade?

Answer (score 1):

`-2146827284` may be represented as `0x80020009‬`, is a [COM Error Code](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd542644(v=vs.85).aspx). That mean `DISP_E_EXCEPTION` - Basic value returned if COM exception ooccured.

Simpliest way to 'convert' singed int to unsigned is to apply bitwise `& 0xFFFFFFFF` operation.

```
>>> error = -2146827284
>>> error & 0xffffffff
‭2147614729‬
```

But nothing special you will see when try to

```
>>> win32api.FormatMessage(error)
Exception occurred.
```