# How to run a macro with Python?

Tags: python, excel, vba

I want to run a Macro with python. I am doing:

```
import win32com.client as w3c

def ejecuntar_macro():
    xlApp_mrapp = w3c.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
    pw_str = str('Plantilla123')
    mrapp = r'D:\Proyectos\Tablero estados\Tablero.xlsm'
    xlApp_mrapp.Visible = True
    xlApp_mrapp.DisplayAlerts = False 
    wb = xlApp_mrapp.Workbooks.Open(mrapp, False, False, None, pw_str)
    xlApp_mrapp.Application.Run("'" + mrapp + "'" + "!Módulo1.guardar_archivo")
    wb.Close(True)
    xlApp_mrapp.Quit()

ejecuntar_macro()
```

but I keep getting an error:

> File ".\ejecucion.py", line 244, in ejecuntar_macro
> xlApp_mrapp.Application.Run("'" + mrapp + "'" +
> "!Módulo1.guardar_archivo") File "", line 14, in Run File
> "C:\Users\Ruben\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py",
> line 314, in ApplyTypes result = self.oleobj.InvokeTypes(*(dispid,
> LCID, wFlags, retType, argTypes) + args) pywintypes.com_error:
> (-2147352567, 'Ocurrió una excepción.', (0, None, None, None, 0,
> -2146788248), None)

Please, Can You help me to solve it?.

Comment: error message looks similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36064723/pywintypes-com-error-2147352567-exception-occurred-0-none-none-none

Comment: I'd try to comment out the last two lines in the function. Probably the file/book is closed before the macros is start. Just a guess.

Comment: `xlApp_mrapp.Run("'" + wb.Name + "'!Módulo1.guardar_archivo")`  You already have the `Application` referenced by `xlApp_mrapp` so no need to add it.

Comment: Hi Tim Willilams. Thanks for your anwwer, You are Right, I  did what you say and it works perfect. Thanks you so much.

Answer (score 1):

I do not believe you need to specify the whole file path of the workbook to run the macro.   You need to specify whole file path to open the workbook, obviously.  But once the workbook is open then to run a macro you only need to specify the workbook name.  So something like the following ...

```
xlApp_mrapp.Application.Run("Tablero.xlsm!Módulo1.guardar_archivo")
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answers.
I solved the error the follows. First, I have to say that in my macro I have a code to close the file. I removed this part.

the code is:

```
import win32com.client as w3c

def ejecuntar_macro():
    xlApp_mrapp = w3c.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
    pw_str = str('Plantilla123')
    mrapp = r'D:\Proyectos\Tablero estados\Tablero.xlsm'
    tablero = 'Tablero.xlsm'
    xlApp_mrapp.Visible = True
    xlApp_mrapp.DisplayAlerts = False 
    wb = xlApp_mrapp.Workbooks.Open(mrapp, False, False, None, pw_str)
    xlApp_mrapp.Application.Run("'" + tablero+ "'" + "!Módulo1.guardar_archivo")
    wb.Close(True)
    xlApp_mrapp.Quit()
```

Comment: great to hear you solved the error! If this answers your original question, please feel free to accept and close your post per https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Comment: Your change is what I recommended in my answer.