# How do I solve this module and string error?

Tags: python, module

```
import xlwings as xw
import pandas as pd
from yahoofinancials import YahooFinancials
import time, os, sys
from enum import Enum

print(
    """
==============================
Dividend & Portfolio Overview
==============================
"""
)

class Column(Enum):
    

    long_name = 1
    ticker = 2
    current_price = 5
    currency = 6
    conversion_rate = 7
    open_price = 8
    daily_low = 9
    daily_high = 10
    yearly_low = 11
    yearly_high = 12
    fifty_day_moving_avg = 13
    twohundred_day_moving_avg = 14
    payout_ratio = 17
    exdividend_date = 18
    yield_rel = 19
    dividend_rate = 20


def timestamp():
    t = time.localtime()
    timestamp = time.strftime("%b-%d-%Y_%H:%M:%S", t)
    return timestamp


def clear_content_in_excel():
    
    if LAST_ROW > START_ROW:
        print(f"Clear Contents from row {START_ROW} to {LAST_ROW}")
        for data in Column:
            if not data.name == "ticker":
                sht.range((START_ROW, data.value), (LAST_ROW, data.value)).options(
                    expand="down"
                ).clear_contents()
        return None


def convert_to_target_currency(yf_retrieve_data, conversion_rate):
    
    if yf_retrieve_data is None:
        return None
    return yf_retrieve_data * conversion_rate


def get_coversion_rate(ticker_currency):
    
    if TARGET_CURRENCY == "TICKER CURRENCY":
        print(f"Display values in {ticker_currency}")
        conversion_rate = 1
        return conversion_rate
    conversion_rate = YahooFinancials(
        f"{ticker_currency}{TARGET_CURRENCY}=X"
    ).get_current_price()
    print(
        f"Conversion Rate from {ticker_currency} to {TARGET_CURRENCY}: {conversion_rate}"
    )
    return conversion_rate


def pull_stock_data():
    if tickers:
        print(f"Iterating over the following tickers: {tickers}")
        df = pd.DataFrame()
        for ticker in tickers:
            print(f"~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~")
            print(f"Pulling financial data for: {ticker} ...")
            data = YahooFinancials(ticker)
            open_price = data.get_open_price()

            
            if open_price is None:
                print(f"Ticker: {ticker} not found on Yahoo Finance. Please check")
                df = df.append(pd.Series(dtype=str), ignore_index=True)
            else:
                try:
                    try:
                        long_name = data.get_stock_quote_type_data()[ticker]["longName"]
                    except (TypeError, KeyError):
                        long_name = None
                    try:
                        yield_rel = data.get_summary_data()[ticker]["yield"]
                    except (TypeError, KeyError):
                        yield_rel = None

                    ticker_currency = data.get_currency()
                    conversion_rate = get_coversion_rate(ticker_currency)

                    new_row = {
                        "ticker": ticker,
                        "currency": ticker_currency,
                        "long_name": long_name,
                        "conversion_rate": conversion_rate,
                        "yield_rel": yield_rel,
                        "exdividend_date": data.get_exdividend_date(),
                        "payout_ratio": data.get_payout_ratio(),
                        "open_price": convert_to_target_currency(
                            open_price, conversion_rate
                        ),
                        "current_price": convert_to_target_currency(
                            data.get_current_price(), conversion_rate
                        ),
                        "daily_low": convert_to_target_currency(
                            data.get_daily_low(), conversion_rate
                        ),
                        "daily_high": convert_to_target_currency(
                            data.get_daily_high(), conversion_rate
                        ),
                        "yearly_low": convert_to_target_currency(
                            data.get_yearly_low(), conversion_rate
                        ),
                        "yearly_high": convert_to_target_currency(
                            data.get_yearly_high(), conversion_rate
                        ),
                        "fifty_day_moving_avg": convert_to_target_currency(
                            data.get_50day_moving_avg(), conversion_rate
                        ),
                        "twohundred_day_moving_avg": convert_to_target_currency(
                            data.get_200day_moving_avg(), conversion_rate
                        ),
                        "dividend_rate": convert_to_target_currency(
                            data.get_dividend_rate(), conversion_rate
                        ),
                    }
                    df = df.append(new_row, ignore_index=True)
                    print(f"Successfully pulled financial data for: {ticker}")

                except Exception as e:
                    
                    exc_type, exc_obj, exc_tb = sys.exc_info()
                    fname = os.path.split(exc_tb.tb_frame.f_code.co_filename)[1]
                    print(exc_type, fname, exc_tb.tb_lineno)

                    df = df.append(pd.Series(dtype=str), ignore_index=True)
        return df
    return pd.DataFrame()


def write_value_to_excel(df):
    if not df.empty:
        print(f"~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~")
        print(f"Writing data to Excel...")
        options = dict(index=False, header=False)
        for data in Column:
            if not data.name == "ticker":
                sht.range(START_ROW, data.value).options(**options).value = df[
                    data.name
                ]
        return None


def main():
    print(f"Please wait. The program is running ...")
    clear_content_in_excel()
    df = pull_stock_data()
    write_value_to_excel(df)
    print(f"Program ran successfully!")
    show_msgbox("DONE!")



wb = xw.Book.caller()
sht = wb.sheets("Portfolio")
show_msgbox = wb.macro("modMsgBox.ShowMsgBox")
TARGET_CURRENCY = sht.range("TARGET_CURRENCY").value
START_ROW = sht.range("TICKER").row + 1  # Plus one row after the heading
LAST_ROW = sht.range(sht.cells.last_cell.row, Column.ticker.value).end("up").row
sht.range("TIMESTAMP").value = timestamp()
tickers = (
    sht.range(START_ROW, Column.ticker.value).options(expand="down", numbers=str).value
)
```

So, this code connects python and excel trough xlwings module and when i run it i get this error and I don't know what to do:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "c:\users\komp\exam\exam.py", line 178, in <module>
    sht = wb.sheets("Portfolio")
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

  File "C:\Users\Komp\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\xlwings\main.py", line 5109, in __call__
    return Sheet(impl=self.impl(name_or_index))
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

  File "C:\Users\Komp\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\xlwings\_xlwindows.py", line 943, in __call__
    return Sheet(xl=self.xl(name_or_index))
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

  File "C:\Users\Komp\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\xlwings\_xlwindows.py", line 236, in __call__
    v = self._inner(*args, **kwargs)
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

  File "C:\Users\Komp\AppData\Local\Temp\gen_py\3.11\00020813-0000-0000-C000-000000000046x0x1x8.py", line 34531, in __call__
    ret = self._oleobj_.InvokeTypes(0, LCID, 2, (9, 0), ((12, 1),),Index
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Ошибка.', (0, None, None, None, 0, -2147352565), None)
```

I tried rewriting the code, reinstalling the modules expecting to be a module or spelling mistake, but it is still not working

Comment: Check out : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36064723/pywintypes-com-error-2147352567-exception-occurred-0-none-none-none